# Dividing count on one table from another and grouping the results

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by, divide

I am trying to calculate the ratio of rows in table A to rows in table B. This would have been easy if I only had to calculate the ratio for the whole sets, but I want to group them by a category that exists in table B.
Table A and B are linked through a primary key (id).

Edit:

I tried the following:

```
select
    (select count(*) from class_a a left join football_players b on (b.id = a.id) group by age)
    /
    (select count(*) from football_players group by age)
```

but the group by command does not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an outer join, then divide count of the rows in the outer joined tables by the total number of rows in the group:

```
select fp.age, 
       (count(cl.id)::numeric / count(*)::numeric) * 100 as ration,
       count(cl.id) as class_count, 
       count(*) as age_count
from football_players fp
  left join class cl on fp.id = cl.id
group by fp.age
```

The cast `::numeric` is necessary to get fractional values, otherwise the result of the division will be converted to an integer.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3373c/3

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52e7/9)

```
select age,
(1-(select count(*) from tableA a where a.id=b.id)/count(*) )*100
from tableB b
group by age
```

Comment: hmm, I tried to work on that for my problem... it is not quite the same case ..?

Comment: Always include your code in your answer, links to external sites go down. And especially SQLFiddle is not that reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This should return what you want:

```
SELECT p.age, 100 * COUNT(c.id) / COUNT(p.id)
FROM football_players AS p
LEFT JOIN class AS c
  ON p.id = c.id
GROUP BY p.age
```

Divide the number of rows from the `class_a` by the number of rows from `football_players`.

Comment: Seems like something I could use, however, age does not exist in class_a, only in football_players.. will this work anyway?

Comment: @Jam: Your query showed `age` in both tables without specifying the table name. Can you add more details about both tables, example data and expected result?

Comment: ye, that was my mistake.. I didn't know how to do it otheriwse (see my table and expected result)